# How to find number by whole digits?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
  var myDay = today.getDate();

  $.fn.wrapInTag = function(opts) {

  var tag = opts.tag || 'td'
    , words = opts.words || []
    , regex = RegExp(words.join('|'), 'gi') // case insensitive
    , replacement = '<'+ tag +'>$&</'+ tag +'>';

  return this.html(function() {
    return $(this).text().replace(regex, replacement);
  });
};

// Usage
$('td').wrapInTag({
  tag: 'td class="calendar-highlight"',
  words: [myDay-15]
});
```

All this script does for me is takes my calendar I have and puts a style behind the current day of the month to signify that it is that day.

This works perfectly for days 10-31 but for days 1-9 it doesn't just highlight the specific day. If its September 1st, the script will apply the style to 1, 10, 11, 12, etc...

How do I make the script so it reads and matches the entire number only?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using the .addClass() function of the jQuery selector rather than mucking about with string replacements on the HTML directly.   It's cleaner, easier and you won't accidentally introduce security holes...

Comment: Thanks, I just found this code on stack overflow as it did what I needed it to do. I really just need to edit it at this point. I've tried a few things but I'm not that intelligent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have much experience with the way you chose to approach this problem it so I figured I could try and suggest an alternate way that is also intuitive:

```
// Get the current day number
var myDay = today.getDate();

// Grab all your td elements, filter them
var currentDateCell = $('td').filter(function() {
    // Will only return true for when the text of the cell is equal
    // to the current date
    return $(this).text() === myDay.toString();
});

// Add your highlight class to the current date cell
currentDateCell.addClass('calendar-hightlight');
```

Hopefully this can help!

Comment: I love it! Thank you so much!